# How to send ARP replies using pcap_sendpacket

Tags: c, networking, pcap, libpcap, arp

I am trying to use `pcap` library for packet sniffing. Till now I have been able to capture IP and ARP packets from my local network traffic. Now, I want to send an ARP request to the default gateway server. I am not sure, but I think I will have to use `pcap_sendpacket` function. I am not getting how to build the arp request, because when I checked the `arphdr` structure defined in `net/if_arp.h`, it is something like this:

```
struct arphdr
  {
    unsigned short int ar_hrd;      /* Format of hardware address.  */
    unsigned short int ar_pro;      /* Format of protocol address.  */
    unsigned char ar_hln;       /* Length of hardware address.  */
    unsigned char ar_pln;       /* Length of protocol address.  */
    unsigned short int ar_op;       /* ARP opcode (command).  */
#if 0
    /* Ethernet looks like this : This bit is variable sized
       however...  */
    unsigned char __ar_sha[ETH_ALEN];   /* Sender hardware address.  */
    unsigned char __ar_sip[4];      /* Sender IP address.  */
    unsigned char __ar_tha[ETH_ALEN];   /* Target hardware address.  */
    unsigned char __ar_tip[4];      /* Target IP address.  */
#endif
  };
```

As it can be seen, the hardware address art is in `#if 0..#endif` block, which means, effectively commented out. I am not understanding why is it done in that way. In order to send an ARP request, I have to fill those fields. Can someone give any suggestion on **how to send one ARP request using pcap_sendpacket and fill those fields in arphdr?**

Comment: You really need to understand ARP, and it is explained in _[RFC 826, An Ethernet Address Resolution Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc826)_, which is the definition of ARP. Each field is explained.

Comment: @RonMaupin Can you tell me how to fill the fields of arp header. The link you provided explains the ARP protocol as a whole... but I didn't find answer to my question.

Comment: Basically, you put in the necessary information: the hardware and protocol addresses and lengths, and the op_code for a request. Just like it explains in the RFC. I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: In that header definition, the hardware address portion has been commented out in the system library itself. The __ar_sha field can't be used. How to fill the hardware address then?